# Visual Studio Code / Angular - Changes to CSS break "Ng Serve" in watch mode

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, compilation, angular-cli, watch

I'm building an Angular App (very new to Angular) and use "Ng Serve" to detect changes in code using its built in 'watch' capability.  That all seems to work very well for TypeScript and HTML, but when it comes to .css files if I'm in the middle of typing a new .css rule, then at the instant when Visual Studio Code decides to recompile it, it will typically cause "Ng Serve" and the watch functionality to break.  I have to Ctrl>C in the terminal to kill the localhost:4200 instance and then re-execute Ng Serve.  It's a time-killer.  Is there a good work-around for this?

Comment: UPDATE: I learned about ng serve --live-reload=false, however this did NOT fix the problem at hand.  While that does prevent the browser from reloading upon changes, it doesn't prevent the compilation of the .css when you make a breaking change by doing something like deleting a semi-colon. Once the compiler breaks on .css, it seems you need to stop ng serve, fix the .css and then restart.

Comment: Frustratingly, you can also set the flag --watch=false which you might think would delay compilation until such time as you manually saved the file(s) <Ctrl-S> that you changed.  Unfortunately, the code seems to not compile at all when you do that even after a save - you still have to quit out from ng serve.